# find duplicated strings to same striing

Tags: python

Having File full of IPS

Source ip.PORT > Destination IP.PORT

> X.X.X.X.PORT > X.X.X.X.PORT

i need to get which `Source Ip` make more requests to `Destination IP`

```
10.20.30.40.80 > 10.50.20.30.1095
10.20.30.40.80 > 10.50.58.64.1066
10.20.30.40.80 > 10.50.20.30.1070
14.15.16.17.443 > 10.50.20.30.7961
```

How can it be possilble to get result that

`10.20.30.40` is duplicated with `10.50.20.30` 2 times which is the highest number from source to destination?

i tried

```
from collections import Counter
with open('log.txt') as f:
    string = f.readlines()
    c = Counter(string)
    print c
```

but it give me the whole duplicated lines

The result i need

`IP 10.20.30.40 is scanning IP 10.50.20.30. It has scanned 2 ports` which is
the highest number of request to same ip with highest range of port [ 2 ]

Another example for result  i need

```
IP 10.30.50.244 is scanning IP 10.20.1.65. It has scanned 1589 ports
```

Comment: Can you say why it should be 3 times and not 2?

Comment: Also, what do you mean by 'it give me the whole duplicated lines'? What is the output you want?

Comment: @L.Grozinger sorry i mean 2 and edited the question

Comment: Do you want to simply ignore duplicate source-destination pairs? Or you want the program to output which pairs are duplicated?

Comment: I need to get which source ip is making highest requests to a destination ip in my example `10.20.30.40` makes more requests to duplicated destination `10.50.20.30`

Comment: @PytHOnAsk Do you need to find that for each destination IP? Can you include the expected output so that it is clearer?

Comment: Isn't the port number supposed to be preceded by a colon `:` instead of a `.`, like `10.20.30.40.80 > 10.50.20.30:1095`

Comment: @AmalK yes but in the log files `10.20.30.40.80` it looks exactly the same `X.X.X.X.PORT`

Comment: Note: python 2 is End of Life, I suggest you switch to python 3 instead.

Comment: None of ips in your example are in your log.txt.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use split() to get the src ip and dst ip. Excluding the port part.
Please see below:

```
from collections import Counter
counter = Counter()
with open('log.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        line = line.strip()
        if not line:
            continue
        src, dst = line.split('>')
        src = src.rsplit('.', 1)[0]
        dst = dst.rsplit('.', 1)[0]
        info = [(src, dst)]
        counter.update(info)
print(counter.most_common(1))
```

which gives me:

```
[(('10.20.30.40', ' 10.50.20.30'), 2)]
```

Comment: If you want to check both sides, you should skip the `ip = line.split('>')[0]` and directly do counter.update([line])

Comment: Probably best to use strip() on the strings to remove whitespace. Also, OP seems to be interested in both columns of the IP not just the first

Comment: if the OP wants both sides, it would be simpler to do `counter = Counter(f)`

Comment: >TypeError: unbound method update() must be called with Counter instance as first argument (got list instance instead)

Comment: How are you calling update? Can you update the question with your latest code?

Comment: Don't use readlines if you're just going to loop over it; just iterate over the file itself instead.

Comment: @Illrnr101 this code exclude the port and get the duplicated lines but that is not the result i need :( i need to find which ip source scanned dest source with more number of port for example `IP 10.30.50.244 is scanning IP 10.20.1.65. It has scanned 1589 ports`

Comment: You can modify it to your needs. Which part is missing?

Comment: @lllrnr101 it is totally don't meet my needs in question :(

Comment: From where did 1589 come in picture?

Comment: @lllrnr101 i just give more examples

Comment: But it is not in your log.txt

Answer (score 0):

You can use a dictionary and the `re` module:

```
import re
counts = {}
with open('log.txt') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    for line in lines:
      pair = re.split(string=line, pattern=r"\.(?=[0-9]{4})")[0]
      if pair in counts:
         counts[pair] += 1
      else:
         counts[pair] = 1 

print(max(counts, key=lambda k: counts[k]))
```

Comment: File "/usr/lib/python2.7/re.py", line 244, in _compile
    raise error, v # invalid expression
sre_constants.error: bogus escape (end of line)

Comment: @PytHOnAsk It was misplaced parantheses. I've fixed it, try now

Comment: here it depends on the most duplicated Source IP with Destination IP excluding the port ..

Comment: @PytHOnAsk Do you want it to count the number of unique ports too? I mean if there are two pairs with the same source and destination IP and the same port, you want it to count only once?

Answer (score 0):

Let's split the problem up into parts.

First, process a single line in the log, taking as input a string like:

`10.20.30.40.80 > 10.50.20.30.109`

And returning some data structure which include the relevant information about source and destination. That is, the source IP, the destination IP and the destination port number. Lets put them in a `tuple`, like this:

```
("10.20.30.40", "10.50.20.30", "109")
```

The code might look like this:

```
line = "10.20.30.40.80 > 10.50.20.30.1095"

source,   dest       = line.strip().replace(" ", "").split(">")
sourceip, sourceport = source.rsplit(".", maxsplit=1)
destip,   destport   = dest.rsplit(".", maxsplit=1)

logentry = (sourceip, destip, destport)
```

In the second line, the input line is stripped of its newlines with `strip()`, then has all whitespace deleted with `replace`, and finally is `split` into two parts by the `">"` character.

To make life easier later, let's define a function to do that work for any line in the log file:

```
def logentry(line):
    source,   dest       = line.strip().replace(" ", "").split(">")
    sourceip, sourceport = source.rsplit(".", maxsplit=1)
    destip,   destport   = dest.rsplit(".", maxsplit=1)
    return (sourceip, destip, destport)
```

So now we can obtain a list of processed log entries from the log file:

```
with open("log.txt") as f:
    logentries = [logentry(line) for line in f]
```

I've made the assumption that the log entries don't contain duplicates. If they do, you can just convert `logentries` to a `set` to get rid of them. Since you are only interested in the number of distinct ports that were scanned, this makes no difference to the result.

```
logentries = set([logentry(line) for line in f])
```

The second part is to find out the most common source IP -> destination IP pairs. So construct a list of these pairs, and use `Counter` to find the most common.

```
counter = Counter([(entry[0], entry[1]) for entry in logentries])
(source, destination), count = counter.most_common(1)[0]
```

The complete example looks like:

```
from collections import Counter

def logentry(line):
    source,   dest       = line.strip().replace(" ", "").split(">")
    sourceip, sourceport = source.rsplit(".", maxsplit=1)
    destip,   destport   = dest.rsplit(".", maxsplit=1)
    return (sourceip, destip, destport)

with open("log.txt") as f:
    logentries = [logentry(line) for line in f]


counter = Counter([(entry[0], entry[1]) for entry in logentries])
(source, destination), count = counter.most_common(1)[0]
```

Now `(source, destination)` is the most common pair of IPs, and count is the number of times that pair appeared. You can report those values something like:

```
print(f"IP {source} is scanning IP {destination}.")
print(f"It has scanned {count} ports.")
```

Comment: First Thank you :) ,,, when i run > TypeError: rsplit() takes no keyword arguments

Comment: Python2.7? In that case, simply `rsplit(".", 1)` will do

Comment: But please try to use Python 3.x

Comment: i appreciate ,, but it does not meet the needs .. it get the most duplicated (source to dest) excluding the port (the most requested dest ip with the same source ip)

Comment: Then I'm afraid I don't understand the requirements as you described them